# How to wrap groups of two elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
```

I want to change it into this:

```
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Surely it's a valid question?

Comment: You did not show or indicate anything that you have already tried to accomplish this.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I normally would - except I found this problem to be very bipolar - either I had the entire thing, or I had no idea at all how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Use this code instead - it's more versatile, as it doesn't rely on the positioning of child elements within the parent:

```
var odds = $("span:odd");
var evens = $("span:even");
var i = 0;
odds.each(function () {
  $(this).add(evens[i]).wrapAll('<div></div>');
  i++;
});
```

---

Figured it out with a bit of searching online:

```
$("span:nth-child(odd)").each(function () {
  $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div></div>');
});
```

`span:nth-child(odd)` means every second `<span>` gets selected. `$(this).add($(this).next())` selects the current `<span>` and the next one, and then `.wrapAll` wraps them collectively in a `<div>` tag.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Pang My mistake - I can't count :)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work when I try it. Should either use `(odd)` and `prev()`, or `(even)` and `next()`. Can you double check?

Comment: OK, I found out why. The `span:nth-child(odd)` selects the 1st, 3rd, 5th... children, so the answer would be different if there are other elements before the spans, even if those are not span elements.

Comment: @Pang you can check my update - it works fine now, here's [the accompanying fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tohs1crb/1/)

Comment: Good one. I guess it would then be even cleaner if you just replace `$("span:nth-child(odd)")` by `$("span:even")` in your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with .slice(), like this:

```
var divs = $("div>div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
   divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```